# JavaScript variables turning into div objects without selectors

Tags: javascript, html, class

Please, tell me what is going on.

Inside a JavaScript class I have 4 variables having the same name as 4 div's IDs. No selectors whatsoever.
Then I put them in an array and when I console log the array they appear as divs.
So how comes those variables turn into div objects without selectors, just by having the same name as the IDs.

[image]

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code. Provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - ideally using a [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers) - to allow others to reproduce this problem :)

Comment: I am sorry if I am breaking some rules. But I put that picture exactly because it kind of reproduces the problem .

Comment: The console has a live reference to the array. So if you *later* assign DOM elements to `arrAllGearsForEngineRunning` elements, you'll see that in your console.log output.

Comment: Barmar The sniped is from Chrome. Otherwise I use Visual Studio 2019. Not VS Code.

Comment: The class fields you’ve created in your class aren’t being used in your example (you’d need to access them via `this`). So they can be removed and your example would still work. See the link above your question as to where those variables are coming from

Comment: Nick Parsons that was it. I removed them and it still worked the same. I am to look into that link.
I guess I could not figure out a correct way to search..